# Radio Button and Checkbox in Material-UI doesn't respond to click nor tap

Tags: meteor, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Meteor + ReactJS and I'm pulling Material-UI via node modules.

```
<RadioButtonGroup name="shipSpeed" defaultSelected="not_light">
    <RadioButton value="light" label="Simple" style={styles.radioButton} />
    <RadioButton value="not_light" label="Selected by default" style={styles.radioButton} />
    <RadioButton value="ludicrous" label="Disabled" disabled={true} style={styles.radioButton} />
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

[Here is what it renders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf2KK.png)

But it won't change values like it's supposed to do on click. It just stays static.

Comment: I've narrow down the error to be a problem with react-tap-event-plugin. I'm using ReactJS with Meteor and calling the module like it says in the MaterialUI docs.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below example. You have to pass valueSelected and onChange props to RadioButtonGroup to get the values of RadioButton. In onChange function set the selected value in state and pass that state to valueSelected that’s all. As simple as that.

```
<RadioButtonGroup
  valueSelected={this.state.cranRadio}
  onChange={this.handleCRAN}
  style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
  name="coin"
  defaultSelected="not_light"
>
  <RadioButton
    value="Yes"
    label="Yes"
    inputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
    style={{ width: "auto" }}
    labelStyle={{ marginLeft: "-10px" }}
  />
  <RadioButton
    value="No"
    label="No"
    style={{ width: "auto" }}
    inputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
    labelStyle={{ marginLeft: "-10px" }}
  />
</RadioButtonGroup>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe having similar issue with Checkbox.

If i provide a handler, then the checkbox is not showing 'tick' when checked. Without handler, the check shows with ripple effect.

```
    import mui from 'material-ui';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
...
    <mui.Checkbox
      label="Employed"
      name="Employed"
      labelPosition="left"
      style={fstyles.checkbox}
      onCheck={props.cb}
    />
```

If I dont provide the onCheck, then the check shows.. should the handler return some value? currently it sets my top level component's state . I tried returning true, but did not help.